# Kendo UI Grid ASP.Net MVC populating from DataTable - Avoid fetching data twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am following the example [here](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/how-to/Binding/grid-bind-to-datatable), and it seems inefficent to me that we call the view with the model (a populated DataTable)

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     DataTable products = Products();             
     return View(products);
 }
```

but it is only used to get the column headings, we must call it again in the "Read" action to actually populate the grid - even though all the data was already available when creating the grid.

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
    @(
    Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
            {
                var c = columns.Bound(column.ColumnName);

            }
            columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
        }) 
  ...

       .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Home"))
```

In the HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            DataTable products = Products();

            if (request.Aggregates.Any())
            {
                request.Aggregates.Each(agg =>
                    {
                        agg.Aggregates.Each(a =>
                            {
                                a.MemberType = products.Columns[agg.Member].DataType;
                            });
                    });
            }

            return Json(products.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to assign the grid data from the DataSet upon creation?

Comment: If you are specifying the read command then don't fetch the load of view,or use the data from view result to bind the grid.

Comment: There is another way to bind [Kendo Grid through JQuery](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index)

Comment: Vinay - I don't quite understand - are you saying all the View without an instance of the Model? I tried that, but of course the Model was empty, so of course I get a NullReferenceException (and there is no way for the grid to get the column names!) Or maybe you mean the same as mmushtaq and to do it by JQuery?

Comment: mmushtaq - I am aware of this, but I specifically wanted to avoid having to specifically set up the particular columns etc - I want a dynamic, general solution to displaying a DataTable in a Kendo Grid. Which the Html helper version seems to provide.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went for decorating the Model class with attributes, and used those.

```
public static void AutoColumnsFromProperties<T>(GridColumnFactory<T> columns, bool multiFilterable = true) where T: class
 {
        //Hidden:
        //
        //<ScaffoldColumn(False)>
        //Public Property RowNum As Integer

        //Order and width:
        //
        //<Display(Order:=0, Name:="Mat Nr")>
        //<GridColumn(Width:=80)>
        //Public Property Material_Nr As String

        foreach (var propertyInfo in ObjectPropertyHelper.GetVisibleProperties(typeof(T), true).OrderBy((x) => Annotations.GetOrderNumber(x, 0)))
        {

            var width = Annotations.GetGridColumnWidth(propertyInfo, null);
            columns.Bound(propertyInfo.Name).Width(width).Filterable((ftb) => ftb.Multi(multiFilterable));

        }
    }
```

And calling code as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.Thingy>()
      .Name("thingy")
      .Columns((x) => KendoGridUtilities.AutoColumnsFromProperties(x))
```

library code:

```
 public class ObjectPropertyHelper
 {
        //Public Shared Iterator Function GetVisibleProperties(Of T)(Optional isVisible As Boolean = True) As IEnumerable(Of PropertyInfo)
        //    GetVisibleProperties(GetType(T), isVisible)
        //End Function
        public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetVisibleProperties(Type type, bool isVisible)
        {

            var props = type.GetProperties();

            for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = props[i];

                if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
                {
                    bool shouldScaffold = Annotations.ShouldScaffoldColumn(propertyInfo);
                    var x = props[i].Name;

                    if (shouldScaffold == isVisible)
                    {
                        yield return propertyInfo;
                    }

                }
            }

        }


    }
```

"Annotations" is a bit of a beast, so I won't post it here, relevant parts are

```
public static bool ShouldScaffoldColumn(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{

            return GetAttributeReturnValue<ScaffoldColumnAttribute, bool>(propertyInfo, (attr) => ((ScaffoldColumnAttribute)attr).Scaffold, true);
        }

 /// <summary>
        /// Calculate a return value from an attribute. See ShouldScaffoldColumn for example usage
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="propertyInfo"></param>
        /// <param name="eval">Function to use when evaluating the attribute's value to return a return value.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static T GetAttributeReturnValue<TAttr, T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Func<object, T> eval, T valueWhenNotFound = null)
        {

            T returnValue = valueWhenNotFound;

            var attrs = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttr), false);

            if (!(attrs == null) && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                var attr = attrs.First();

                if (!(attr == null))
                {
                    returnValue = eval(attr);
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```